# Use Coldfusion array as a counter

Tags: arrays, sorting, coldfusion

I am using a two-dimension Coldfusion array as a counter to keep track of different number of occurrences.  However, I am finding it is taking a long time to process due to the large array declaration.  This is how I am doing it:

```
<!--- retrieve data from the first db --->
<cfquery datasource="xxx" name="mylist">
SELECT id,sequencenum,pattern1
FROM mydatabase
ORDER BY sequencenum DESC LIMIT 10
</cfquery>

<!--- initialize the array --->
<cfset myarray = ArrayNew(2)>
<cfloop index = "i" from = "1" to = "8000">
    <cfset myarray [#i#][1] = i>
    <cfset myarray [#i#][2] = 0>    
</cfloop>

<!--- start accumulating. adigit can be any numbers from 1 to 8000 and can repeat  --->
<cfoutput query="mylist">
     <cfquery datasource="xxx" name="mylist2">
     SELECT adigit
     FROM mydatabase
     WHERE pattern2 = #pattern1#
     AND sequencenum < #sequencenum#
     LIMIT 1
    </cfquery>
    .....
    <cfset myarray[adigit][2] = myarray[adigit][2] + 1>
</cfoutput>

<!--- sort them in descending order --->
<cfloop index="outer" from="1" to="#arrayLen(myarray )#">
 <cfloop index="inner" from="1" to="#arrayLen(myarray )-1#">
    <cfif myarray [inner][2] lt myarray [outer][2]> 
         <cfset arraySwap(myarray ,outer,inner)>
    </cfif>
 </cfloop> 
</cfloop>
```

The adigit field can be any number from 1 to 8000.  All the repeating adigit should be accumulated.  For example, if adigit=45 occurs 12 times, then myarray[45][1] = 45 and myarray[45][2] = 12.  However, the resulting array with a value may only be 400 out of 8000.  The rest will all be 0 because they have no matching adigit.

Due to all the "unused" array and the sort, it is taking longer than usual to process.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I found the issue is actually with the sort at the end.  It is sorting through 8000 elements array even when myarray[adigit][2] = 0

So I am trying to remove all the array elements with myarray[adigit][2] = 0 with this:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(myarray)#">
    <cfif #myarray[i][2]# eq 0> 
        <cfset arrayDeleteAt(myarray,i)>
    </cfif> 
</cfloop>
```

But I am getting an error:

> The element at position 2, of dimension 2, of an array object used as
> part of an expression, cannot be found.

How to properly reduce the array size by removing all that has myarray[adigit][2] = 0?

Comment: you can use a ColdFusion structure (a dictionary) instead of a two-dimensional array to store and manipulate your data.

Comment: Surely it's possible, using sorting and grouping, to pre-sort your results with the query rather than needing to use such a loop?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is change this:

```
<cfoutput query="mylist">
     <cfquery datasource="xxx" name="mylist">
     SELECT adigit
     FROM otherdatabase
     WHERE pattern2 = #pattern1#
    </cfquery>
    .....
    <cfset myarray[adigit][2] = myarray[adigit][2] + 1>
</cfoutput>
```

to something like this:

```
 <cfquery datasource="xxx" name="mylist">
 SELECT adigit
 FROM otherdatabase
 WHERE pattern2 in (valuelist from previous query)
 ORDER by adigit
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="myList">
<cfset myarray[adigit][2] = myarray[adigit][2] + 1>
</cfoutput>
```

After that it's hard to say because it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I added the LIMIT 10 in "mylist". But the issue is even if I put LIMIT 1, the process still takes a while. I expect it to be just a few seconds, but it's not. I am suspecting it is the cfloop that initialize the 8000 array that is taking a long time. Sorry, I added a sequencenum.  The resulting match must have a sequencenum less than the original one.

Comment: @Jack eh, the query-in-loop issue was certainly *a* cause of your slowdown, but it's also possible for your other loop to be a separate problem. i'd suggest starting with one of the two solutions provided, and than expanding on them to do the work of the double loop within the query itself too. Seems to just be some basic sorting?

Comment: @KevinB with just one record taking minutes doesn't make sense.  Not sure the solution will work because I need to associate the pattern with the sequencenum.  That sort at the end also should take up too much time at all.

Comment: @Jack i feel like at this point we're just guessing. Have you tried doing some logging to see what specifically within this code is taking so long to run? Sure, with one record it should be effectively instant. If it isn't, step one should be figuring out why so you can isolate.

Comment: @KevinB it seems that it is the sorting that is taking up the time!  It is sorting 8000 empty arrays.  How can I fix this without changing the content of the non-zero array?

Comment: keep digging through the loop. What within it is taking long enough to add up, over that many iterations, to produce that delay? you'll likely find that you need another approach entirely

Answer (score 0):

You're using an `n + 1` approach to filter your data in the application. You've run one query (`mylist`), then you're looping over it and running a query (a Query of Query in this case) for every record in the first.

```
 <cfoutput query="mylist">
      <cfquery datasource="xxx" name="mylist">
      </cfquery>
 </cfoutput>
```

If `mylist` returns 10 records, you're running 11 queries. If it returns 1000 records, then it's 1001 queries.

Like Dan's answer, I think the solution lies in updating your SQL to filter the data in the database first. You shouldn't be trying to filter the data in the application; the DB is better suited.

For example, this filters out all of the `adigit` values that don't have a match to `pattern1`:

```
SELECT 
    a.adigit
FROM 
    otherdatabase a 
INNER JOIN 
    mydatabase b ON b.pattern1 = a.pattern2
```

Then, you can see how many occurrences there are of each matching record:

```
SELECT 
    a.adigit
    , COUNT(*) as adigit_count
FROM 
    otherdatabase a 
INNER JOIN 
    mydatabase b ON b.pattern1 = a.pattern2
GROUP BY 
    a.adigit
```

This query should return the two necessary values in a single request, eliminating the CF array and all looping.

Comment: I added the LIMIT 10 in "mylist".  But the issue is even if I put LIMIT 1, the process still takes a while.  I expect it to be just a few seconds, but it's not.   I am suspecting it is the cfloop that initialize the 8000 array that is taking a long time.

Comment: Found the issue is with the sort. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the sorting issue.  Just by reversing the "from" and "to" order to remove all the array elements with myarray[adigit][2] = 0  before sorting:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="#arrayLen(myarray)#" to="1" step="-1">
    <cfif #myarray[i][2]# eq 0> 
        <cfset arrayDeleteAt(myarray,i)>
    </cfif> 
</cfloop>
```

After removal of thousands of 0 elements, the sort works so much faster now.